# Any benefit to sticking with a particular hotel chain on US East Coast?

Tags: usa, hotels

I am planning a trip to the US East Coast in August 2016. The idea is to drive from Boston to New York and perhaps Washington stopping at various places on the way. Duration will be around 8-9 days.

Is there any advantage to choosing a hotel chain and only staying there when possible? I do not live in the US and would only be needing accommodation for this trip so I assume loyalty cards etc would be of little use to me.

Comment: Be aware, many chains have hotels in Europe too. You could for example get a free day in the Munich Hilton or such, or the Berlin Crowne Plaza, or a weekend in the Vienna Marriott. That depends on your price range; Super 8 and Motel 6 for example have no presence in Europe (as far as I know)

Comment: Purely one man's opinion: totally not worth bothering about at all.

Answer (score 3):

The benefits of hotel status can kick in starting from a relatively low level. For example, Hyatt Platinum can be obtained after just 5 stays. Correspondingly, however, you can expect [relatively little benefit](http://www.hyatt.com/gp/en/benefits/membership_platinum.jsp) after such a small committment. A sample comparison of mid-level hotel loyalty programmes is available [here](http://travelsort.com/blog/how-to-compare-hotel-programs-mid-tier-elite-benefits) and you will see there isn't much you'll be eligible for after 9 days.

An alternative to hotel status is using a booking site's loyalty programme. There aren't that many of those, but a comparison is available [here](http://www.headforpoints.com/2015/04/16/the-alternative-to-hotel-loyalty-schemes-hotels-com-and-welcome-rewards/). Notably, hotels.com awards you a one night stay (at average cost) after 10 nights of bookings with any hotel.